# How to retain blank cells while removing other duplicates?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am working in Excel and want to delete cells based on an ID number (which is one of the variables). However, when I use the 'remove duplicates' function, it will also delete duplicate blank cells (missing values).

How do I prevent Excel from deleting the blanks, but at the same time remove identical ID's?

Example of my data:

```
    text    favorited   created id  statusSource    screenName  retweetCount    isRetweet   retweeted
1   RT @cdavandaag: De hashtag #ikstemCDA is deze maand al 7.500 (!) keer gebruikt, fantastisch. Op naar een mooi uitslag. #CDA #PS15 http://t.…    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:58 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  Cecile2511  25  TRUE    FALSE
1   @Sanderderouwe @CDA @InfoPCN Standpunten CDA check: http://t.co/PqBCn3o8N1  FALSE   17-3-2015 13:57 5,77831E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>  CannaKieswijzer 0   FALSE   FALSE
2   RT @Matthijs85: Ligt het trouwens aan mij                               
3   @PuckPetrus bang makerij bemoei je niet met je buurman les 1                                
4   RT @FrankScholman: Het #CDA kiest #LagereLasten! Hier hebben we 7 goede redenen voor: http://t.co/utQt0LfEzl. #NOSdebat #PS15 #MeerBanen ht…    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:57 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  gijsdupont  4   TRUE    FALSE
5   RT @Jan_Slagter: In Hilversum werden de Buma awards uitgereikt, en  Buma wint het #nosdebat #cda    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:56 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  Ztrmarco    38  TRUE    FALSE
6   RT @StSteenbakkers: Peiling Maurice de Hond: tweestrijd VVD en CDA! Stem CDA!!! #Lagerelasten #CDA #100pBrabant FALSE   17-3-2015 23:56 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  gijsdupont  5   TRUE    FALSE
7   @PuckPetrus  dat ze ze blijven doen 30 jaar lang                                
8   RT @cdavandaag: .@SybrandBuma pleit tijdens #NOSdebat voor #maatschappelijkedienstplicht. Waarom? Lees meer: http://t.co/5HkCxRrOO8. http:/…    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:55 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  Cecile2511  48  TRUE    FALSE
9   RT @Pran_Westerdam: Stem niet op de PVDA, VVD, D66, GL en CDA: niets doen wordt onze totale ondergang, dat erkennen zal als eerste moeten g…    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:55 5,77982E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>  worrienie   2   TRUE    FALSE
10  RT @NederlandKiest: Buma (CDA): Rutte moet kijken naar de Nederlander. De toekomst van onze kinderen is er een met leenstelsel en hoogste s…    FALSE   17-3-2015 23:54 5,77981E+17 <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>  Cecile2511  34  TRUE    FALSE
11  CDA-lijsttrekker Marianne van der Sloot: ‘We sluiten geen partijen uit, ook de PVV niet’ http://t.co/br8gFUTAuH FALSE   17-3-2015 23:53 5,77981E+17 <a href="http://www.citytweet.nl" rel="nofollow">Citytweet</a>  EindhovenNL 0   FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: Please use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html or the like for posting your input table, and add the desired output table (or a least make it clear what it should be).

Answer (score 2):

You could just sort the data to set aside the rows with missing values at the bottom of the spreadsheet. Then select just the rows from which you want to remove the duplicates, and use the 'remove duplicates'button.